# Shibboleth integration with my .net website 

Tags: shibboleth

I need to integrate shibboleth in my application. My application is .net web application. May I know how to do this one? I have a separate server (ubuntu server) in which shibboleth idp and sp installed with apache configuration.

I made lot of search on this. but I can't able to get the correct information for this one Can anyone suggest me some url or point what i need do to get it work?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement (Windows Identity Foundation) WIF in your ASP.NET Web App.

If you have Active Directory Federation Services (which basically make Active Directory speak SAML2 protocol and WS-Federation protocol), you can have ASP.NET with WIF trusting (thru WS-Federation) ADFS V2, trusting (thru SAML 2 protocol) Shibboleth.
You can find additional information in [these posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/tags/idmgt). You can find sample screen shots with SharePoint instead of ASP.NET in this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avec_windows/archive/2011/05/16/web-sso-sharepoint-224-l-aide-de-shibboleth.aspx) (sorry it's in French). A white paper explains [how to implement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjguin/archive/2010/12/20/livres-blancs-sur-ws-fed-saml-sharepoint-white-papers-on-ws-fed-saml-sharepoint.aspx).

If you don't have Active Directory and ADFS V2, you may want to use SAML2 protocol extension for WIF and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733318/can-shibboleth-be-integrated-with-windows-azure-access-control-service/8735858#8735858) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to : [Single Sign on using Shibboleth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826824/single-sign-on-using-shibboleth)