# Can Shibboleth be integrated with Windows Azure Access Control Service?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth, accesscontrolservice

Two of our higher-ed clients use Shibboleth for SSO. I have zero experience with Shib, and do not have an instance to test with.

Ultimately we would like to integrate a Shib SSO with these clients in our Windows Azure (MVC) web role. So my questions are:

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, how? Do any settings need to be make on Shib, and what are they?

I spoke with Vittorio Bertocci last year at MIX 11 about this. He told me there is a checkbox called "WS-Federation" that can be enabled in Shib, which would enable compatibility. I've learned from out clients that [WS-Fed is supported on the Service Provider but not the Identity Provider](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/DEV/Supported+Protocols).

I will be more than happy to supplement this question with more details in response to comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Azure side, you would use [WIF](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4451) which has [extensions](http://connect.microsoft.com/site1168/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=36088) to implement SAML 2.0 protocol (apparently still in CTP).
You would not use ACS in between in this case.
Warning: there are some [gotchas while using WIF with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621496/asp-net-mvc-2-and-authentication-using-wif-windows-identity-foundation)

:-)
Benjamin

Comment: Funny I actually subscribe to the Claims-Based Identity blog. Sure enough, this CTP post was in my rss feeds archive. They haven't posted anything else since July... any idea if they changed their blog to a different RSS url? Trying to find out how much longer this will be in CTP...

Answer (score 0):

If Azure supports SAML 2.0, then it will, more or less, interoperate with Shibboleth. If it only supports WS-Federation, then it won't for your purposes.